# OnClick event of nested React component is not firing with Firefox or IE11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

I have the following render method inside my main component. I have attached a onClick event to an img element nested inside another component and calling the main component's function. This works using Chrome and Edge but not from Firefox or IE11. I need it work for all.

How do I set it up so I can have my onIconClick event wired up for all?

```
class LookupFieldItem extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
     super(props);
     this.onIconClick = this.onIconClick.bind(this);
    }
    onIconClick(e) {
     ......
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
                <TextInput field={field} className={_className} inputRef={inputRef} fieldMetadata={fieldMetadata} value={value} onChange={onChange} onKeyDown={this.onKeyDown}>
                  <div className="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-default">
                      <img src='/Content/images/LookupIcon.png' onClick={this.onIconClick} />                                                
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </TextInput>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Update with transpiled code block**

```
_react2.default.createElement(
                            'button',
                            { type: 'button', className: 'btn btn-default' },
                            _react2.default.createElement('img', { src: '/Content/images/LookupIcon.png', onClick: function onClick() {
                                    return console.log('lookup icon');
                                } })
                        )
```

Comment: did you found a solution for this?

Comment: @monkeyjums actually I found a solution in my code, maybe it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue, I found that the `onClick` was not being passed to the image (using react-dev-tools I could trigger it programatically) so the problem was where it was defined, so change from this:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-default">
    <img src='/Content/images/LookupIcon.png' onClick={this.onIconClick} />                                                
</button>
```

to this:

```
<button type="button" className="btn btn-default" onClick={this.onIconClick}>
    <img src='/Content/images/LookupIcon.png' />                                                
</button>
```

it is not a binding issue, it looks like some predefined prop is being sent down from the button if it is not defined.

my issue was the same, the difference was that I was wrapping a `Glyphicon`

Comment: Not only for react, it's generally a bad idea to have some onclick event handlers inside of a button or link element. These elements have their own event handlers out of the box and perform a default action when you click them.

Answer (score -2):

Let's start with the simplest thing we can do first.

`onClick={this.onIconClick.bind(this)}`

Does it work now?

Comment: No it doesn't work. I should edit the code to show that i do bind that function inside the constructor this.onIconClick = this.onIconClick.bind(this);

Comment: yeah.. thanks. what if you tried `onClick={() => console.log('clicked')}`. Does this work?

Comment: I bet the event should trigger, it just can't not to

Comment: if it does, then next question - what is inside your event handler? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, thanks, nothing special really. But wait a sec, what is that TextInput component wrapping the problematic area around? Are you sure it's not intercepting the event? What if you commented TextInput out, leaving just what's inside it..